# Can a function be called in if region and checked whether the function returns true or false?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code

```
 function highlight()
{
var field=document.forms["signin"]["username"].value;
if(field.length==0)
return false;
}
```

I write another function

```
function check()
{
 if (highlight()==false;)
 {
alert('message');
 }
}
```

Can i call the function that way in the if region and check whether the function returns false?

Comment: You should tell us...

Comment: Yes, you can, but you need to make sure your function returns true when you don't want it to return false. Or you can use the exactly-equal-to operator `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. The `hightlight()` expression will get evaluated and turn into its return value, then proceed on to the `== false` check.

The main issue I see is that you `return false` from inside the `if` statement, but if you don't get inside that, you'll never return anything.

A function that returns nothing becomes `undefined`, which is falsey, which will always trigger your alert from the second `check` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `false` or `undefined`. Both `false` and `undefined` equate to `false`, so that check will always be true. Fix it like this;

```
function highlight() {
    var field=document.forms["signin"]["username"].value;
    if(field.length==0)
         return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `===` instead of `==`, because while it is true that `undefined == false`, it is not true that `undefined === false`.